# Exchange+Outlook 2013 - Read Mails turn Unread

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2013

I have a local EX2013 server and several Outlook 2013 clients. Some of the clients occasionally (once or twice a day) see a random read email turn unread with no apparent reason.

I went through the delivery logs in exchange,  and looks like some messages have 2 or more records for delivery (same message, but only one record is readable, other give error when you want to read them). I also looked at the spam filter and I only see one record of the mail going in, not multiple as I saw on delivery reports.

I also went through mail header, but there is nothing special there.

Has anybody noticed this before? What do you think I should be checking?

Here's the delivery report on ECP. Same mail shows there three times. Only one of them is visible, the other 2 gives an error when you want to open it up. The report itself is very simple, nothing to be seen there (I would have to leave out pretty much everything for privacy reasons anyway)

[image: delivery]

Comment: Do the clients also have mobile devices or secondary devices syncing email as well?

Comment: At least two users have their mailbox only on a single device. No mobile devices.

Comment: And they show as unread in OWA as well?  I'm curious if you were to force a user to use OWA for an entire day if it would still happen.  I would claim it was an Outlook issue except for the strange records in the message logs (could you post a screenshot of the message log for one of the emails?)

Comment: I will ask one of the users to use outlook, and ask to open up OWA to see if the mail also turns unread in there. This is not exactly what you wanted to know but can give us some info. I'll add the screenshot.

Comment: Another note: When a mail turns unread, it also becomes unread on OWA.

Comment: I would suggest installing the latest CU7 on Exchange.

Comment: I don't remember which CU it was but I did the latest a few weeks ago